electron-builder nsis-web is downloading package from url
I'm new in electronjs framework, I build simple application (dark-mode app tutorial from electronjs website) and then I package it using electron-builder targeted with windows web installer (nsis-web)
I upload x.nsis.7z in github realeses.
package.json:
win:{
 "target": "nsis-web"
},
"nsisWeb":{
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "license": "./LICENCE"
    },
 "publish":{
      "provider":"generic",
      "url": "https://github.com/AlijonMurodov/dark-mode/releases/download/1.0.0/dark-mode-1.0.0-x64.nsis.7z"
    }

url is working but web setup.exe is said that 404 url not found
code example
